# I can't understand the following proof from *Bak,Newmann* Complex Analysis:

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

I can't understand the following proof from *Bak,Newmann* Complex Analysis:

If $C_1,C_2$ are smoothly equivalent then $\int _{C_1} f=\int _{C_2} f$

I assumed $C_1=z(t): a\leq t\leq b$; $C_2=w(t): c\leq t\leq d$

$f(z)=u(z)+iv(z);z=x+iy$

Since $z,w $ are equivalent then there exists a $1-1$ mapping $C^1$ mapping $\lambda(t):[c,d]\to [a,b]$ such that $\lambda(c)=a,\lambda(d)=b,\lambda^{'}(t)\leq 0$ and $w(t)=z(\lambda(t))$

**After doing a few lines he writes that $\int_c ^ d u(z(\lambda(t)))x^{'}(\lambda (t))\lambda ^{'}(t) dt =\int _a ^bu(z(t))x^{'}(t) dt $
by the change of variable theorem for ordinary integrals**

I can't understand thebold lines how is this transformation done .Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps suppressing the forest of parentheses will help. Let's write $g = (u \circ z) \cdot x'$.  Then the first integral is

$$\int_c^d g\big(\lambda(t)\big) \lambda'(t) \, dt$$

whereas the second integral is

$$\int_a^b g(s) \, ds$$

(I am using $s$ rather than $t$ here to hopefully make more clear what the change of variables is). So under the change of variables $s = \lambda(t)$, do you see how it fits together?